# $x''= \frac{Ax+B}{Cx+D}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Might there be a closed-form solution to the second-order differential equation below?$$x''(t)=\frac{Ax+B}{Cx+D}$$ If not, is there any way to get a power series approximation *in terms of the variables*, without having to use any initial conditions? Or absolutely anything somewhat close to the answer? (If it helps we have $x(0)=x'(0)=0$ but the constants $A,B,C,D$ are unknown and must be left as variables.)

Comment: @Voliar If $AD = BC$ then the numerator is a multiple of the denominator and hence we get a differential equation $x'' = E$.

Comment: @CareBear They are constants in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: what's the problem with $\int\frac{Cx+D}{Ax+B}d^2x=\int dt^2$?

Comment: @Aditya You've just rewritten the equation...

Comment: Cool problem, though finding analytical solutions seems very hard. If you want to gain some intuition on how the solutions look like: The ODE describes a particle rolling down the potential $V(x) = -\frac{Ax}{C} + \frac{AD-BC}{C^2}\log\left(x +\frac{D}{C}\right)$. Depending on the signs of $AD-BC$, $A/C$, $D/C$ the potential takes different forms and can be seen to lead to 1) oscillating behavior (when the potential has a minimum) 2) forever growing solutions (when $A/C > 0$ roughly) 3) finite time singularity (when $D/C < 0$).

Answer (score 2):

Let $v=x'(t)$ and $a=x''(t)$:

Then $$a=v\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{Ax+B}{Cx+D}\\
\int vdv=\int \frac{Ax+B}{Cx+D} dx\\
\frac{v^2}2=\frac{(BC-AD)\ln(Cx+D)+ACx}{C^2}+k\\
v=\frac{dx}{dt}=\sqrt{2\frac{(BC-AD)\ln(Cx+D)+ACx}{C^2}+k'}\\
\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{2\frac{(BC-AD)\ln(Cx+D)+ACx}{C^2}+k'}}=\int dt\\f(x)=t+c$$
I suppose there is no closed form of $f$

Comment: Thanks, that's a start. Maybe a power series could help to get an implicit equation of $x$ in terms of $t$?